# Subclassed view's uiimage not appearing as IBDesignable

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable

I have set up a subclassed `UIView`, and want to see the embedded image in IB - so I've set it as `IBDesignable`

```
@IBDesignable

class DieView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var dieImage : UIImage = UIImage()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateLayout()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        updateLayout()
    }

    // for IB
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        updateLayout()
    }

    func updateLayout() {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
        let profileImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "dice1")
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false

        self.addSubview(profileImageView)


    }

    func showNumber(number: Int) {

    }

}
```

The background colour changes, but the embedded image doesn't update. Why not?

Comment: You don't use that image anywhere, why it should appear?

Comment: It's added as a subview. It appears at runtime, so what method would be used to make it appear on the storyboard?

Comment: I don't see that image is being added anywhere in the code, I can see only this `UIImage(named: "dice1")` is being used.

Comment: profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "dice1")
which is then added to the parent self.addSubview(profileImageView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402908-prepareforinterfacebuilder) of the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`:

> Interface Builder waits until all objects in a graph have been created
>   and initialized before calling this method. So if your object’s
>   runtime configuration relies on subviews or parent views, those
>   objects should exist by the time this method is called.

which says that subviews should exist before this method is called. I'm not sure, but try to add image view before this is called. Also, you have to keep in mind that `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` is called independently by interface builder. Read the docs for more info. Good Luck!